# Alternative to Font.createFont()?

Tags: java, performance, fonts, awt

I need to load a font from file and I noticed that `Font.createFont()` takes about 5 seconds to complete per font creation. Here is the relevant excerpt from my resource management class:

```
    try(InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(FONT_DIR + fontName + FONT_EXT))
    {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Font awtFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in); //<-- This operation takes about 5 seconds
        System.out.println("Operation took: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);

        awtFont = awtFont.deriveFont(fontSize);
        result = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, antiAlias);

    }
```

I checked similar posts but I couldn't find a solution to this. So my question is: Is there a faster way to create a java.awt.Font from file or am I doing something terribly wrong? 

Thanks for your time and have a good day!

Alex

Comment: I know nothing of Java, but faced a similar issue in SpriteKit/Objective C. It turned out I was loading the entire font family and all variants of that font. It took 4-6 seconds. When I used a different method that loaded only a specific style (e.g. Regular or Bold) it took 100ms.

Comment: Initially I thought the delay might me due to the availability of the font in the system. But it turns out that whether the font is present or not in the system the delay remains the same.. Also it is a single regular font so I don't think it's due to the number of fonts loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createFont(int fontFormat, InputStream fontStream)` creates a new file when the file already exists (which requires/checks write permissions - another cost of performance).

So if you want to create a font from a stream - unfortunately there are no alternatives. Note, that this is actually very convenient, when for example font is packed in a JAR.

For that reason there is another static method

`createFont(int fontFormat, File fontFile)`

As you have a font as a file, it is convenient and better to use this one.

It is much more efficient and convenient for those cases - and much faster (not creating vs creating of temp file)

An average it would be 3 times faster as a result.

Answer (score 0):

What's the output of your code line

```
System.out.println("Operation took: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000);
```

? When I let your code run on my machine, loading a font takes around 43ms (milliseconds). Nano btw means 1 billionth - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nano-. So if you compare nano seconds and divide them by 1,000,000, you get milliseconds, not seconds.

If it still takes long on your system - have you tried caching the generated fonts. How many different fonts is your code about to generate? I see taht you have three variables that make up your generated fonts: `fontName`, `fontSize` and `antiAlias` - how many permutations do you have?

Comment: The output of the sysout is 5439.. I know that nano = 10^-9 of a second.. Else the delay would not be noticeable..

Comment: I just load one regular font from file

Comment: If you just load one font, apply one size and one antiAlias settings, you should cache the generated Font. It will then only take 5s once, not every time you need the Font. Is that acceptable for you?